# Is there a way to revert back to regular Vim from vim-go (possible plugin)?

Tags: vim

Recently began using vim-go (or Ultimate vim) but I am not pleased with it. Is there an easy way to revert back to the regular vim that I was using and get rid of this vim-go entirely? I am assuming this vim-go is just a plugin as I am not very experienced with it.

Comment: Uninstall vim-go, reinstall vim.

Answer (score 2):

Since [vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go) is a plugin, you can just delete it from your vim directory (`~/.vim` on UNIX-like systems or `~\vimfiles` on ms-windows).

Look for `vim-go` in `~/.vim/bundle`, `~/.vim/pack/plugins/start` or `~/.vim/plugged` and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
$ vi ~/.vimrc
```

Remove the line: 
`Plug 'fatih/vim-go', { 'do': ':GoInstallBinaries' }`

From:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'fatih/vim-go', { 'do': ':GoInstallBinaries' }
call plug#end()
```

At the end your `.vimrc` should looks like this:

```
call plug#begin()
call plug#end()
```